# flag provided but not defined in nginx prometheus exporter

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, prometheus

I'm tryin to deploy an nginx prometheus exporter (https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-prometheus-exporter) in a kubernetes cluster but if I use param "-nginx.scrape-uri" in the args tag it fails. If I remove it then it works but use default values "127.0.0.1:8080"

How should I pass this parameter?

Here my deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-prometheus-exporter
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    k8s-app: nginx-prometheus-exporter
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: nginx-prometheus-exporter
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: nginx-prometheus-exporter
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/path: "/metrics"
        prometheus.io/port: "9113"
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-prometheus-exporter
        image: infra-harbor-paas.attmx-ne.local/matrixx_lab01/nginx/nginx-prometheus-exporter:0.8.0
        args: ["-nginx.scrape-uri http://10.150.152.206:8080/stub_status"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9113
          name: http
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
```

And here the error that it throws

```
oscar@dlmx:~$ kubectl logs nginx-prometheus-exporter-84f6f6bfd5-9rv6h -n monitoring
flag provided but not defined: -nginx.scrape-uri http://10.150.152.206:8080/stub_status
Usage of /usr/bin/exporter:
  -nginx.plus
        Start the exporter for NGINX Plus. By default, the exporter is started for NGINX. The default value can be overwritten by NGINX_PLUS environment variable.
  -nginx.retries uint
        A number of retries the exporter will make on start to connect to the NGINX stub_status page/NGINX Plus API before exiting with an error. The default value can be overwritten by NGINX_RETRIES environment variable.
  -nginx.retry-interval value
        An interval between retries to connect to the NGINX stub_status page/NGINX Plus API on start. The default value can be overwritten by NGINX_RETRY_INTERVAL environment variable. (default 5s)
  -nginx.scrape-uri string
        A URI or unix domain socket path for scraping NGINX or NGINX Plus metrics.
        For NGINX, the stub_status page must be available through the URI. For NGINX Plus -- the API. The default value can be overwritten by SCRAPE_URI environment variable. (default "http://127.0.0.1:8080/stub_status")
  -nginx.ssl-ca-cert string
        Path to the PEM encoded CA certificate file used to validate the servers SSL certificate. The default value can be overwritten by SSL_CA_CERT environment variable.
  -nginx.ssl-client-cert string
        Path to the PEM encoded client certificate file to use when connecting to the server. The default value can be overwritten by SSL_CLIENT_CERT environment variable.
  -nginx.ssl-client-key string
        Path to the PEM encoded client certificate key file to use when connecting to the server. The default value can be overwritten by SSL_CLIENT_KEY environment variable.
  -nginx.ssl-verify
        Perform SSL certificate verification. The default value can be overwritten by SSL_VERIFY environment variable. (default true)
  -nginx.timeout value
        A timeout for scraping metrics from NGINX or NGINX Plus. The default value can be overwritten by TIMEOUT environment variable. (default 5s)
  -prometheus.const-labels value
        A comma separated list of constant labels that will be used in every metric. Format is label1=value1,label2=value2... The default value can be overwritten by CONST_LABELS environment variable.
  -web.listen-address string
        An address or unix domain socket path to listen on for web interface and telemetry. The default value can be overwritten by LISTEN_ADDRESS environment variable. (default ":9113")
  -web.telemetry-path string
        A path under which to expose metrics. The default value can be overwritten by TELEMETRY_PATH environment variable. (default "/metrics")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-prometheus-exporter
        image: infra-harbor-paas.attmx-ne.local/matrixx_lab01/nginx/nginx-prometheus-exporter:0.8.0
        args: 
        - "-nginx.scrape-uri=http://10.150.152.206:8080/stub_status"
```

Comment: Thanks I think it was rigth answer, now i get this message:  2020/10/02 16:22:41 Starting NGINX Prometheus Exporter Version= GitCommit=
2020/10/02 16:22:46 Could not create Nginx Client: failed to get http://10.150.152.206:8080/stub_status: Get "http://10.150.152.206:8080/stub_status": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
but I guess nginx needs expose the uri for metrics, Am I right?

Comment: Yes, "http://10.150.152.206:8080/stub_status" URL should expose metrics.